# how do i vertical align middle div2 and div3 inside this wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I spent hours trying to figure out how to vertical align middle .div2 and .div3? 
Hope someone out there can help me. Thanks so much. you guys are the best. 
Any answers would be appreciated.
[image]

```
 <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .wrapper{
            border: 4px solid black;
            width:900px;
            height:100px;
            text-align: center;
            display: table;
        }
        .div1,.div2,.div3{
            background: gray;
        }
        .left{
            float: left;
        }
        .right{
            float:right;
        }
        .center{
            display: inline-block;
            margin:0 auto;
            line-height: auto;
        }
        .clear{
            clear:both;
        }
        span{
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span>
        <div class="left div1">
            <p>div1</p>
            <p>div1</p>
            <p>div1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="center div2">
            <p>div2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right div3">
            <p>div3</p>
            <p>div3</p>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean "vertically center" when you say "vertically align"?

Comment: yes vertical align middle

Comment: Do you have a minimum browser you need to support? Also, you should put your code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so it's easy for us to look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This css

```
<style>
p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808080;
    }
.div1, .div2, .div3 {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 450px;
}

</style>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PX66f/)

Comment: Yeah, display: table; is the only way you are going to get this to happen.

Comment: Although it works it is ugly. Wrapping divs in <p> styled as table inside div styled as cell ... brrr. Just use 'display: table-cell' on .div1,.div2 and .div3. No need for some wrapping harakiri :D

Answer (score 1):

please check the below code.

url : http://jsfiddle.net/VqGJN/

```
  <div class="wrapper">
<span>
    <div class="left div1 cell">
        <p>div1</p>
        <p>div1</p>
        <p>div1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center div2 cell">
        <p>div2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right div3 cell">
        <p>div3</p>
        <p>div3</p>
    </div>
</span>
```

css :

```
.wrapper {
    display:table;
}
.wrapper span {
    display:table-row;
}
.wrapper .cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:200px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Just note: you don't have to specify display:table and display:table-row on parent elements which allows you to omit any unnecessary wrappers. Simply specify display:table-cell on "column" divs and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: inline-block`: (*Added inner-wrapper to contents in HTML*)

**CSS**

```
    * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .wrapper {
        border: 4px solid black;
        width:900px;
        height:100px;
        text-align: center;
        display: table;
    }
    .div1, .div2, .div3 {
    }
    .center, .left, .right {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        vertical-align:middle;
        line-height: auto;
    }
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
    span {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .left > div {
        float: left;
    }
    .right > div {
        float: right;
    }
    .center > div {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .inner-wrapper {
        background: gray;
    }
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqGJN/4/)**

Comment: Good lord. This turned into competition how to do this with the most wrappers as possible now? Use answer from Renjith, it is the cleanest solution (almost)

Comment: @Mroz it is not a copy paste contest going on here. I am showing how it can be done if the content is wrapped in html. this is just another way. We can't say which one is better or worst when comes to layouting html.